# Read specific content file from tar.gz files without extracting

Tags: command-line, grep

I wish to write the result of these below conditions in a file:

1. in a specific folder, I have many `tar.gz` files.
2. each `tar.gz` file contains `.dat` file in sub folders.
3. I wish to get the full path of these `.dat` files, if I find in it a specific word (`ERROR24`).
4. all this without extracting the `tar.gz` files

I have found and tested the below one that writes in a file the result, but I don't how to look in a `tar.gz` file.

```
grep -rlw --include="*.dat" -e "ERROR24" /home/tests/logs > /home/files/data/result/listErrors.txt
```

Can you please help update the previous one in order to get the same result but searching in `tar.gz` files?

Comment: Use `zgrep` instead on `*.tar.gz` files

Comment: thanks for your advice.
(i can't test right know... i don't have my linux laptop... tomorrow i'll be able to). i'll test with zgrep -rlw --include="*.dat" -e "ERROR24" /home/tests/logs > /home/files/data/result/listErrors.txt

Comment: hello
it is not working... i am getting this :

"/usr/bin/zgrep: -rlw: option not supported"   

do you another solution please?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to use `zgrep` on compressed archives, however what you're doing is adding `-r` to the options list, which is not supported by `zgrep` [which comes with Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187879/85039).

`-r` is used for recursive traversal of directory tree. We can do the same with `find` command, and use `-exec` flag to run `zgrep` on each compressed archive that is found.

Since I don't have any example of archives you use, the command below is just an example. Adjust as necessary:

```
find -type f -name "*.tar.gz" -exec zgrep -a "ERROR24" /home/tests/logs > /home/files/data/result/listErrors.txt  \;
```

Note that `-l` here can't really be used, because it only lists filename of archive itself. Alternatively, you could always use `zcat` and filter its output with `grep`, but that's probably more hassle than necessary.

Comment: thanks for you help. (i am a newbie). i have tried your advice and i am getting "-exec: command not found"

Comment: if i use the pipe | instead of -exec, i am not getting the error but i have no result. meaning it is not working.

Comment: @JamesJimmy Sorry, exec should be terminated with `\;`. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

IF you mean just viewing what's within the archive you can simply change what it opens in or does from the right-click menu whenever you click on the archive. As in resetting the default application/action.

I know for a lot of archives the default action now is to mount it... for whatever reason or to automatically extract.

Or are you looking for a command-line oriented solution?

Comment: command-line oriented solution = yes i am. there are too many archive, impossible to do it manually. so please advise how i can do it? thanks