# grep to search word in a file and result given that word with ZIPfile name that contain that word

Tags: command-line, files, directory, grep

Here is what I am doing: I want to find which zip files includes this number with number itself for example i want the result be like this :

```
7505857289 AIRCDR
```

where the number is my search result and `AIRCDR`is zipfilename that contains this number among 100000 files

Comment: Actually, probably [grep — list file name where match is found](https://askubuntu.com/q/587197/295286) will be more suitable

Comment: Basically, just do `grep -rH '7505857289'  <directory_name>`. `-r` is for recursive search down directory tree, and `-H` to include filename. If you run into `Argument list too long` error, use `find -type f -exec grep -H '7505857289' {} \;`

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy thanks for your comment but not sure if my question wasn't clear or you didnt get it 
i said i have i +1000000 of CDR zip files i want to find 7505857289 with file names that contain that number  as u said grep -rH '7505857289' is working but not here............................                      
this is example of my files 
AIRCDR9876_20180605-232341.AIR_6567.gz
AIRCDR9877_20180605-232842.AIR_6568.gz
AIRCDR9878_20180605-233343.AIR_6569.gz

and here is command which didnt work:
gunzip -c AIRCDR9* |strings|grep -rH '7505857289'

Comment: @AliCisco Alright, your original post didn't mention zip files, so it was indeed unclear and when you say `file` it just means regular file. The information you posted in the comment just now should be inside the question itself, so please edit that so that others can see it.

Comment: See if this one helps:    https://askubuntu.com/q/971701/295286

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy thanks for your help ,my bad corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment the “haystack” of your search is a set of **g**zipped text files (based on the file name extension `.gz`). You can scan them with the [`zgrep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/zgrep.1.html) command, a wrapper around the `grep` command that decompresses gzipped files on the fly and supports most of the same options as `grep` itself.

Thus you can simply run

```sh
zgrep -oHe 7505857289 <FILES>...
```

which will print the name of the source file followed by a colon and the matching character sequence for each match.

If you need a specific output format I recommend that you transform it. For matching text followed by a space and the source file name that would be:

```sh
zgrep ... | sed -re 's/^([^:]*):(.*)$/\2 \1/'
```